# Django - Rendering Markdown Sanitizied with Bleach

Tags: python, django, html, markdown

When I do markdown(text), without bleach, I get the desired result (raw):

```
<p>blah</p>
```

and it displays correctly as:

```
blah
```

where the "p" tags are rendered correctly as a paragraph block.

When I do bleach.clean(markdown.markdown(text)), I get (raw):

```
&lt;p&gt;blah&lt;/p&gt;
```

and it displays incorrectly as:

```
<p>blah</p>
```

where the "p" tags are part of the text and not an HTML paragraph block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the `bleach`ed HTML as safe

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

...
    return mark_safe(bleach.clean(markdown.markdown(text)))
```

But, there is also [django-bleach](https://bitbucket.org/ionata/django-bleach.git/) that provides integration with Django and ready-made tags to use bleach in Django.

```
{% load markdown_deux_tags bleach_tags %}
{{ view_user.profile.about|markdown:"user"|bleach }}
```

In `settings.py` you can tell django-bleach what tags are okay

```
BLEACH_ALLOWED_TAGS = ['h1', 'h2', 'p', 'b', 'i', 'strong', 'a']
BLEACH_ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['href', 'title', 'style']
BLEACH_ALLOWED_STYLES = ['font-family', 'font-weight']
BLEACH_STRIP_TAGS = True
```

etc.